# Deploy a web application with tomcat included in one jar

Tags: java, tomcat, jar, tomcat8

I need to create a simple jar containing my Tomcat8 setup and my web application war.

Why? I want to create a portable web application, meaning that you can host it anywhere, on a linux, windows, mac, whatever. The only thing needed is the jar file, and all your data is saved in a "data" folder created in the folder containing the current jar file.

The goal is to create a jar file you that just have to start to start tomcat and it's done, your web application is ready and listening.

I don't know if it is even possible, but I found nothing using google.

PS: I will use VAADIN7(for the web app), Jersey JAX-RS(for a rest api) and Neo4j (for the datas)

Comment: This question is both too broad and off-topic since you're looking for a tool or piece of software. That said, have a look at Spring Boot - it can work with Jersey and embeds Tomcat.

Comment: yes it's a bit off topic I know :/ I found nothing and wanted to be at least oriented on a solution

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in this blog entry:
[Standalone web application with executable Tomcat](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/11/standalone-web-application-with.html)

You can use a [`tomcat7:exec-war` maven goal](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/exec-war-mojo.html) to create self executable jar with all tomcat classes.

> So you will be able to use only: `java -jar createjar.jar` to run your
>   webapp without need to install an Apache Tomcat instance.

You have to extend your `pom.xml` with this plugin entry:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>tomcat-run</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>exec-war-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <path>/application</path>
                <enableNaming>false</enableNaming>
                <finalName>application.jar</finalName>
                <charset>utf-8</charset>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Build your application: `mvn package`

And run Tomcat along with your embedded application: `$ java -jar application.jar`

Alternatively, check this Heroku tutorial describing the process of creating a web app with embedded Tomcat: [Create a Java Web Application Using Embedded Tomcat](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat).

Comment: seems good to me but is it possible to deploy a war app in tomcat embedded? VAADIN is producing a war file so I need to include a war file as webapp in tomcat

Comment: The [Standalone web application with executable Tomcat](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2012/11/standalone-web-application-with.html) post explains how to convert your existing WAR project into one with embedded Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks for your good reply :) even if it's a bit off-topic ^^"

Answer (score 1):

I was able to run the project within 10 minutes just followed the instructions on http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#quick-start

Spring boot is amazing in the sense that it packages all the necessary things we need and helps reduce development cost on infrastructure etc. Helps devs focus on delivering the actual business value.

Micro services ( as i have mentioned in multiple threads) is achiveable and made easy with this spring boot approach.